# Pelican: include file's contents on main page

Tags: python, pelican, static-site-generation

Noob Pelican question here:

I want to include content on the main page of my pelican site that is not blog-related posts, but which simply reads an rst file and puts the results on the main page. I could put a single post together, but that really isn't what I want.

I can of course hack the index.html template and put the text directly there. But what I'd like to do is put some code there that would parse a file and put the same text there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the benefits of using Python as the settings file format is that Pelican can do what you want without having to write a plugin or modify Pelican itself.

Let’s say you have some introductory content stored in `intro.rst` that you want to be rendered in your `index.html` template. The following additions to your Pelican settings file will result in a new `INTRO` variable that contains the rendered contents of the `intro.rst` file.

```py
from pelican.settings import DEFAULT_CONFIG
from pelican.readers import RstReader

config = DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
# If you need to override default settings (e.g., DOCUTILS_SETTINGS / DEFAULT_LANG):
# config["DEFAULT_LANG"] = "de"

# .read() returns (content, metadata). Keep content only; we don’t need the metadata.
# Assign content to an ALL-CAPS variable to access from template:
INTRO, _ = RstReader(config).read("path/to/intro.rst")
```

With the above settings in place, you should be able to insert the rendered content by placing the `{{ INTRO }}` variable in the desired place in your index template.

Comment: It’s obvious when you put it like that. But thanks!