# Pelican not rendering rst title and subtitle from imported rst file

Tags: restructuredtext, pelican

I want to import an rst file to my Pelican index page like here:
[Pelican: include file's contents on main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64637275/pelican-include-files-contents-on-main-page)

```
*****
Title
*****

subtitle
########

subsubtitle
***********

Here is some content in the document.
**ReStructuredText** (rst): plain text markup

.. image:: images/22204100065.png
   :alt: exhale
   :width: 512px
```

only from subsubtitle gets the page rendered as html.
The source of the index.html looks like this

```
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-zinc-800 p-4 md:p-6 mb-4 rounded-lg"><div class="section" id="subsubtitle"> <h2>subsubtitle</h2>
```

Here is some content in the document. **ReStructuredText** (rst): plain text markup

The start of the index.html template looks like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% block content_title %}
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-zinc-800 p-4 md:p-6 mb-4 rounded-lg">{{ INTRO }}</div>
{% if not category and not tag %}
<div class="my-12 md:my-24 text-zinc-800 dark:text-zinc-300">

  {% if SOCIAL or FEED_ALL_ATOM or FEED_ALL_RSS %}
```

The part of my settings file looks like this (from the answer of above link):

```
from pelican.settings import DEFAULT_CONFIG
from pelican.readers import RstReader
config = DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
INTRO, _ = RstReader(config).read("content/incls/sample.rst")
```

I expect the Title be rendered in h1 and the Subtitle in h2.

I am using the Papyrus theme. Update: I also tried with notmyidea but have the same problem.

I tried to ask the question in a comment of the above link but I am not allowed.

Comment: What is in your main page? I suspect that the main page already has a title and subtitle, with which the included file conflicts.

Comment: @StevePiercy there are the summaries of the article below, which have all titles and subtitles from their rst sources.  I tried with template without h1, still the same does not get rendered.
The source of the index.html looks like this 
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-zinc-800 p-4 md:p-6 mb-4 rounded-lg"><div class="section" id="subsubtitle">
<h2>subsubtitle</h2>
<p>Here is some content in the document.
<strong>ReStructuredText</strong> (rst): plain text markup</p>
<img alt="exhale" src="images/image.png" style="width: 512px;"/>
</div>
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do not paste code in comments because it is unformatted and illegible. Please update your question instead. Also I mean the source of the `index.rst`, not the rendered HTML.

Comment: @StevePiercy Thank you, I don't have index.rst, only index.html template. I updated my question.

Comment: What do you have in your [Pelican settings file](https://docs.getpelican.com/en/latest/settings.html)?

Comment: @StevePiercy I updated my question. It's from the answer of the link in my question.